# How do I format a date value for a 3-column date drop-down widget?

Tags: forms, datetime

I would like to pass a date in the format `2013-04-23 00:00:00` as a `#default_value` into a form builder function:

```
$form['date'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#default_value' => $my-array['date'],
);
```

...but the form renders dates in a three column drop-down widget (which I want to keep). How do I reformat my date and/or form builder function so that my three drop-downs display 23 Apr 2013? At present, they display 02 Feb 1900.

Thanks

**Solution**

See @tostinni's answer for half of the soluion. This is the second half:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($my-array['date']);
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$month = date('n', $timestamp);
$year =  date('Y', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Form API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#date) will help you figure this out, you'll have to pass an array with the `year`, `month` and `day` keys like this:

```
$form['date'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#type' => 'date',
    '#default_value' => array('year' => 2013, 'month' => 4, 'day' => 23),
);
```